# WooCommerce Custom Product Designer user specified dimensions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[WooCommerce Custom Product Designer](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-product-designer/10959830) <strike>dosen't have any demo version or even admin demo and I'm wondering if there is an option to let user set their own product size. I've tried to contact plugin devs but with no luck.</strike>

They've added admin demo without ability to save and see changes. Still no option for letting customer set dimensions (set not choose).

What I'm trying to achieve is a print house store for photo wallpapers.

1. User can upload image and based on it set custom dimension of wallpaper.
2. If size exceeded print size it will show slices.

Similar result can be found here (it's based on PrestaShop): [Example](https://translate.google.pl/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pl&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwyklejony.pl%2Fdruk-z-twojego-zdjecia&edit-text=&act=url)

If there is better option then Custom Product Designer please point me there.

Comment: So far as my research, there is no such solution for letting customer set their own dimension.

Comment: @ucheng for this particular plugin or for any other solution?

Comment: For this plugin, also for other solutions. You may need to do some customizations for the plugin, but I think it will take lots effort. I have used other plugin named Fancy Product Designer for my client, and I found some users ask for the similar feature request on the  comments.

Comment: I have an idea, please see the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for letting customers set their own dimension. The plugin I use is [Fancy Product Designer](https://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-product-designer-woocommercewordpress/6318393)

In the product setting at admin, you can upload a base template and allow the user to resize it. So the user can resize the width and height to the ratio they wants. See the demo [gif](http://g.recordit.co/57mOhs2ARY.gif).

And you need to add the width and height custom fields for user to set the real print size they want. You could use [WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator](https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/) to calculator the price, so the user will know how much they have to pay.

**Please note that, this is just a rough idea, I can't guarantee it works.**

**ADD**: I find the WooCommerce Custom Product Design allows you to set the dimension at product builder but not to lock the width and height. , so the user can resize it to the width/height ratio they want just like how I did at Fancy Product Designer.[image]

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce Custom Product Designer has Admin and Live Demos :)
http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-product-designer/full_screen_preview/10959830?_ga=1.15721270.1626147379.1480044710

Here is live demo link
http://wordpress.tshirtecommerce.com/demo/

For admin demo go here and solve the math problem and click “Create Demo” a new sandbox will be created for you.
http://wordpress.tshirtecommerce.com/backend/

Checkout an product design intro video here...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXcCDyEW59k

I think it will do what you want and much more ;)
Just upload plain paper image as product image, and your clients will be able to add image (and also text) to it... ;)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Did you look at the example I've given?